# Get coefficients and p values from a list of models, while holding out a county or year one at a time

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel dataset in long format of the following form:

```
library(lfe)

## Create long format dataset. Unit of analysis is county-year, 
## i.e. one observations equal a county in a given year. 
## Independent variable, x is a dummy (0, 1)

year <- c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009)
county <- c("county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5", 
           "county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5")
x <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
y1 <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7, 2, 3, 13, 17, 4.5, 1.3)
y2 <- c(6.5, 2, 3, 18, 2, 14, 7.6, 2.4, 8.2, 4.9)
y3 <- c(5.2, 2, 5, 7.5, 5, 9, 3, 1.7, 2.5, 5.3)

D <- data.frame(year, county, x, y1, y2, y3)
```

I create a model.list that contains all the models.

```
model.list = vector(mode = "list", length = 3) # Pre-allocating list to store fitted models, as long as your outcomes.
j = 1 # Counter.
for (i in c("y1", "y2", "y3"))
{
  temp.dta = data.frame(y = D[, i], D[, (!colnames(D) %in%  c("y1", "y2", "y3"))]) # It selects the outcome at each iteration.
  model.list[[j]] <- felm(y ~ x | factor(county) + factor(year) | 0 | county, data = temp.dta) # Stores fit in list, j-th position.
  j = j + 1 # Increase counter.
}

summary(model.list[[1]]) # Model fitted on y1.
```

I'd like to extract coefficient estimates, and p-values for each outcome while one county is held out from the regression. And then get the output in a tidy way. E.g. data frame.

Comment: Hi @pheb, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Define three models
# Fit each model 5 times and hold out one county each time

library(lfe)

m.all <- list()
m.sets <- list()
for (y in c("y1", "y2", "y3")){
  for (cnty in unique(D$county)){
    temp.dta <- D[D$county != cnty, c(y, "year", "county", "x")]
    m <- as.formula(paste0(y, "~ x | factor(county) + factor(year) | 0 | county"))
    m.sets[[cnty]] <- felm(m, data = temp.dta)
  }
  m.all[[y]] <- m.sets
}
```

```
# Extract model summaries

summary.all <- list()
for(y in c("y1","y2","y3")){
  summary.set <- sapply(1:length(m.all[[y]]), function(i) summary(m.all[[y]][[i]])$coefficients)
  row.names(summary.set) <- c("coef", "se", "tval", "pval")
  summary.all[[y]] <- t(summary.set)
}
```

Result where each matrix corresponds to a model formula (different response variable), and each row of each matrix corresponds to fits with different datasets (one county held out each time). Row one is where County1 was held out, row 2 is where County2 was held out, etc.

```
summary.all
#> $y1
#>           coef       se       tval      pval
#> [1,]  0.950000 2.369921  0.4008572 0.7272946
#> [2,]  2.383333 1.217888  1.9569398 0.1894915
#> [3,] -0.675000 1.674627 -0.4030749 0.7258989
#> [4,] -1.366667 1.217888 -1.1221613 0.3784205
#> [5,]  1.250000 2.188194  0.5712473 0.6254679
#> 
#> $y2
#>           coef       se       tval       pval
#> [1,]  1.625000 3.481967  0.4666902 0.68662273
#> [2,]  6.533333 1.194242  5.4706946 0.03182644
#> [3,]  3.650000 3.543617  1.0300210 0.41126692
#> [4,] -1.166667 1.194242 -0.9769097 0.43164030
#> [5,]  2.775000 3.836403  0.7233339 0.54463260
#> 
#> $y3
#>            coef       se       tval      pval
#> [1,]  0.2500000 1.542725  0.1620509 0.8861576
#> [2,]  2.6333333 1.043636  2.5232287 0.1276717
#> [3,]  2.0250000 1.531498  1.3222348 0.3170465
#> [4,] -0.3666667 1.043636 -0.3513356 0.7588970
#> [5,]  1.1250000 2.049509  0.5489120 0.6381607
Created on 2022-04-01 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```